# SQL oracle get value of a column in a row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Two tables.
The first one `'table_fields'`

```
Type    Name    Label
ORG     text1   organisation
ORG     text2   location
PERS    text1   manager
PERS    text2   gender
PERS    text3   age
```

The second one '`table_data`'

```
 Type   ID      text1   text2       text3   text4
ORG     Sven    HR      Brussels        
PERS    Ludo    theo    male        43  
ORG     Sara    MR      Barcelona
```

What I try to do is a table like table_Fields with two extra columns that represents the ID of my table_data and the value of the specific column for a specific Name in the table_fields.
My result should be like:

```
Type    Name    Label           ID_table_data   VALUE
ORG     text1   organisation    Sven            HR
ORG     text2   location        Sven            Brussels
PERS    text1   manager         Ludo            theo
PERS    text2   gender          Ludo            male
PERS    text3   age             Ludo            43
ORG     text1   organisation    Sara            MR
ORG     text2   location        Sara            Barcelona
```

I don't know if something like that is possible in SQL Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNPIVOT`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da914/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_fields ( Type, Name, Label ) AS
SELECT 'ORG',     'text1',   'organisation' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ORG',     'text2',   'location' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERS',    'text1',   'manager' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERS',    'text2',   'gender' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERS',    'text3',   'age' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_data ( Type, ID, text1, text2, text3, text4 ) AS
SELECT 'ORG',  'Sven', 'HR',   'Brussels',  NULL, CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR2(20) ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL   
SELECT 'PERS', 'Ludo', 'theo', 'male',      '43', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ORG',  'Sara', 'MR',   'Barcelona', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT f.*,
       d.id,
       d.value
FROM   table_data
        UNPIVOT ( value FOR name IN (
          text1 AS 'text1',
          text2 AS 'text2',
          text3 AS 'text3',
          text4 AS 'text4'
        ) ) d
        INNER JOIN table_fields f
        ON ( f.type = d.type AND f.name = d.name)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da914/4/0)**:

```
| TYPE |  NAME |        LABEL |   ID |     VALUE |
|------|-------|--------------|------|-----------|
|  ORG | text1 | organisation | Sven |        HR |
|  ORG | text2 |     location | Sven |  Brussels |
| PERS | text1 |      manager | Ludo |      theo |
| PERS | text2 |       gender | Ludo |      male |
| PERS | text3 |          age | Ludo |        43 |
|  ORG | text1 | organisation | Sara |        MR |
|  ORG | text2 |     location | Sara | Barcelona |
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an `INNER JOIN` like:

```
    SELECT t2.*
        ,t2.ID AS ID_table_data
        ,CASE 
            WHEN t2.NAME = 'text1'
                THEN d.text1
            WHEN t2.NAME = 'text2 '
                THEN d.text2
            WHEN t2.NAME = 'text3 '
                THEN d.text3 
            END As VALUE
FROM table_fields t1 INNER JOIN table_data t2 ON t1.Type = t2.Type
```

**EDIT:**
As per MT0 comment which I had not realized at the beginning, I edited adding CASE statement to match expected result

Comment: This will not match `table_field.name` with the appropriate `table_data` column and transpose the columns to rows.

Comment: @MTO why should we want this in the 1st place?

Comment: If `type` is `ORG` then the `text1` column represents `organisation` and if the `type` is `PERS` then it is `manager`. You are not performing this match so the data this query presents will not make sense. Effectively you are doing a `CROSS JOIN` since all `table_field.label` values will be joined to all `textN` columns - which is wrong.

Comment: Because of the requirement? Value should be based on the column from table table_data that matches column name from the table table_field. It is not text1 - it may be text1, text2, text3 or text4 (in OP's example up to text4).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to use `UNPIVOT`, which was suggested by MT0, due to version incompatibility (e.g. you are using Oracle version below 11g) this may work for you:

```
with table_fields (type, name, label) as
(
  select 'ORG', 'text1', 'organisation' from dual union all
  select 'ORG', 'text2', 'location' from dual union all
  select 'PERS', 'text1', 'manager' from dual union all
  select 'PERS', 'text2', 'gender' from dual union all
  select 'PERS', 'text3', 'age' from dual
),
table_data (type, id, text1, text2, text3, text4) as
(
  select 'ORG', 'Sven', 'HR', 'Brussels', null, null from dual union all
  select 'PERS', 'Ludo', 'theo', 'male', '43', null from dual union all
  select 'ORG', 'Sara', 'MR', 'Barcelona', null, null from dual
)
select tf.type, tf.name, tf.label, td.id id_table_data,
       case
         when tf.name = 'text1' then td.text1
         when tf.name = 'text2' then td.text2
         when tf.name = 'text3' then td.text3
         when tf.name = 'text4' then td.text4
         else null
       end value
  from table_fields tf
 inner join table_data td on (td.type = tf.type);
```

Comment: Rather than using the legacy comma-join syntax (which is difficult to read and cannot handle full outer joins), you could use the ANSI-92 standard join syntax `FROM table_fields tf INNER JOIN table_data td ON ( tf.type = td.type )`.

Comment: @MT0 I just did that, although I personally do not agree with the general consensus that we should all switch to SQL-92. In my opinion SQL-89 syntax is easier to read; I even find Oracle syntax for outer joins easier to read than SQL-92 (unless it is full outer join obviously) - but this is probably more a matter of personal preference and old habits. I do agree that SQL-92 should be generally used in answers though, especially since questions are usually asked by novice Oracle developers who have just started picking habits.